# Create numbered list in KnockoutJS using each item's position in an observable array for the numbers

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I would like to create a numbered list and use knockout to bind the data. The data binding works fine, but I am unable to come up with a way to smoothly generate the numbers based on their position in the observable array. The observable array may vary in the future, so I would like knockout to dynamically handle the numbering of the list.

Here is my html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list" data-bind="foreach: sidebarItems">
    <li class="" data-bind="css: isActive">
        <a href="#dropdowns" data-bind="text: text"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my Javascript code:

```
self.sidebarItems = ko.observable([
    {text: 'Option'}, 
    {text: 'Option'}, 
    {text: 'Option'}, 
    {text: 'Option'}, 
    {text: 'Option'}
]);
```

I would like the list to say:
1 - Option
2 - Option
3 - Option
etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

Use `$index`:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list" data-bind="foreach: sidebarItems">
    <li class="" data-bind="css: isActive">
        <a href="#dropdowns" data-bind="text: $index() + text()"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

2 options.

1. Change your `ul` to `ol`
2. Use the knockout `$index` variable (like `text:$index` in the foreach)